# ¿Como puedo guardar una variable $_session en un array?

Tags: php

Quisiera preguntar como podria guardar la variable session en un array, estuve intentando no logro añadir la variable a un array

```
<?php
session_start();
$array1 = file("ids.txt");
$test = array_push($array1, $_SESSION['u_id']);
file_put_contents("ids.txt", implode( PHP_EOL, $test));
```

Answer (score -1):

Codigo:

```
$array = array('dato' => $_SESSION['u_id']);
```

Comment: Mejorarias la calidad de tu respuesta si la justificas

Comment: Te recomiendo que cheques [¿Como escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Para asi evitar malas calificaciones o respuestas absurdas.Saludos